# Suprema and infima of subsets of Real Numbers and The Completeness Property of R.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let S = {1$\ $-$\ $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$:n ∈ N}. Find the Infimum and Supremum of S.

When I simply put the values of n, I find that the  greatest element is 2 and the least element is $\frac{1}{2}$.
How can this be solved analytically?

Comment: The 2nd term is negative, so it would contribute most (least) to the total term for odd (even respectively) values of n. Now consider the denominator of the second term. How does it change with n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same argument can be used to show both assertions. Let $f(n) = 1-\frac{(-1)^n}n$. Notice that $\big\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\big\rvert = \big\lvert\frac1n\big\rvert < 1$ if $n\geq 2$. Therefore, for every $n$ odd, $f(n)\leq f(1)$ and for every even $n$, we have $f(n)\geq f(2)$.

Therefore, $\inf S = f(2)$ and $\sup S = f(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

2 séquencies:
- Even sequence increasing, begining with the value 1/2 ( for n=2 ) and finishing with the value 1 ( at infinity )
- Odd sequence, which is decreasing, begining with the value  2 ( for n= 1)
 and finishing with the value 1 ( at infinity )
So we have the gretest element 2 and thés mal l'est element 1/2.